# Google Polymer listening for fire event never happens

Tags: javascript, polymer

Putting together the not fully working examples from here https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#events

I am trying to get the addEventListener to work on a different component or dom element.
If I put the listener on the submitting component it will work but going from the example if I put it on a dom element nothing happens.
Having the listener on the sending element seems redundant.

I looked at data binding but I want to pass more data and really just want to build a library of working small demo bits I can reference when I need the different methods.

Thank you.

```
<body unresolved id="body">

 <polymer-element name="say-hello" attributes="name" on-click="{{sayHi}}">
   <template>Hello {{name}}!</template>

   <script>
     Polymer('say-hello', {
       sayHi: function() {
        console.log("sklngh");
         this.fire('said-hello', {name: this.name});
       }
     });
   </script>

 </polymer-element>


 <say-hello></say-hello>

 <div id="container">zzz</div>

 <script>
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    // var container = document.querySelector('say-hello');
    container.addEventListener('said-hello', function(e) {
      alert('outside: Said hi to ' + e.detail.name + ' from ' + e.target.localName);
    });
 </script>

</body>
```

Edit

Ah it bubbles! Needed to wrap the component.

```
<div id="container">
    <say-hello></say-hello>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See edit above. That seems to be the answer. Kazam.

Answer (score 0):

To fire a custom event from the host element use the fire method. You can also pass in data to event handlers as an argument to fire.

Use this link:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events